# Why might SQL execute more quickly on SQL Server 2000 when NOT using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan

I could see nothing wrong with the execution plan. Besides, as I understand it, SQL Server 2000 extended many of the performance benefits of stored procedures to all SQL statements by recognising new T-SQL statements against T-SQL statements of existing execution plans (by retaining execution plans for all SQL statements in the procedure cache, not just stored procedure execution plans)

It's a fairly straight forward SELECT statement with sensible table joins, no transactions included or linked servers being referenced within the query and WITH (NOLOCK) table hints applied. The stored procedure was created by dbo and the user has all the necessary permissions.

So my question is this:

What are the likely reasons for a query to take only a few seconds to run but then take several minutes when identical T-SQL is run via a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Can think of two possible reasons:

- The stored procedure might be using an outdated execution plan.  If you drop and recreate the stored procedure, its execution plan will be recompiled.
- A stored procedure is optimized for the general case.  If you execute a query with specific values, SQL Server might find a better execution plan just for those values.  If this is the case, adding `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` to the non-procedure version should make it slower.

Comment: This happens on a specific database on a particular server and does so for quite a few stored procedures. Dropping/recreating has had no effect. Running the query with parameterized values ala NHibernate works significantly better generally (for the tests I ran) so this appears not to be related to any particular values. This is in production and "works" but it's something I'd like to demystify.